# enclosed current of non-constant current density

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to find the enclosed current for a non-constant current density equal to $\vec{J}=J_0y^2\hat{x}$. I think I should just be finding $I_{enc}=\int\vec{J}\dot{}d\vec{a}=J_0 y^2\int_{x_0}^{x_f} dx$ right? I'm a little uncertain about if the dot product in the integral.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing what the $d\vec{A}$ stands for in your integral. $d\vec{A}$ is the differential area element. When you are calculating the enclosed current, there is *some* area that the current passes through. Look at this picture:

[image: Magnetic Flux.]

In the case above, you have a magnetic field that is going through some area $A$, and so $\int \vec{B} \cdot \, d\vec{A}$ is the magnetic flux through this area. Thus $\int \vec{J} \cdot \, d\vec{A}$ you can think of as the current density flux through an area, and you are integrating over the area.

Another question you might ask is why is $\vec{dA}$ a vector? The differential area element is defined as $$d\vec{A} \equiv A \hat{n},$$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector in the direction that is **perpendicular** to the area. Check this out below: [image: Area element.]

As you can see, the normal unit vector is at a right angle with the area, so the dot product picks out the component that is **parallel** to this normal direction.

In conclusion, when you are calculating the current enclosed in some area, you must first find $d\vec{A}$, then take the dot product with your current density and integrate over the whole area (surface, which will be a double integral). Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So if the area is just a square in the x-y plane, then $d\vec{A} = dx dy$? or does it equal $ dx \hat{x} + dy \hat{y}$?

Comment: It would be $dxdy\hat{n}$, and then you have to find the normal depending on how it is oriented. For example, if the loop is just in the $x$-$y$ plane, then the normal would stick out of the page so it would be $d\vec{A} = dxdy \hat{k}$.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Then the integral is equal to $0$ since it'll be $\hat{x}\dot{}\hat{z}$ right?

Comment: Yea if the loop is in the $x$-$y$ plane and the current is in the $x$ direction then the normal and the current are perpendicular, so $0$ flux.